# It there a way to mount a single S3 object as a file?

Tags: amazon-s3, mount

There are tools such as [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) and [goofys](https://github.com/kahing/goofys) that make it easy to mount S3 buckets or subdirectories on a local filesystem.

Is there a way to mount a non-directory S3 object as a single file so that the OS can perform the regular `open`, `read`, `write` and `seek` operations on it?

Comment: It is not recommended to mount Amazon S3 as a volume. It is an object storage system, not a filesystem so synchronization errors can occur. You should use the S3 API or the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to copy content locally.

Comment: I understand that. Unfortunately, for existing C libraries such as HDF5 there is simply no existing way to use the S3 API without rewriting a lot of code. Mounting an object as a file provides a workable solution. There is a performance penalty, but in many use cases this is acceptable. And copying an entire file is wasteful if one need only read a small portion of it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to mount a single file *period*, regardless of its source. Mount operations only apply to directories (real or otherwise).

Comment: You're right. The word *link* would have been more appropriate. I'm wondering if it's possible to implement something like `ln -s s3://blah/file.txt local-file.txt`.

Comment: Not unless you can get `s3://blah/` as part of the VFS.

Answer (score 0):

s3backer allows mounting a bucket as a single file:

https://github.com/archiecobbs/s3backer